# C program is giving a too many arguments warning

Tags: c

So I have this code where I try to solve some simple math:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

float ruutvorrand(float a, float b, float c);

int main(void) {  
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
    float solution;

    printf("Ruutvõrrandi lahedamine\nSisesta andmed: ");
    scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);
    solution = ruutvorrand(a, b, c);
    printf("Ruutvõrrandi lahendid on: ", solution);
    return 0;
    }

float ruutvorrand(float a, float b, float c) {
    float out;
    float upper;
    float upper1;
    upper = sqrt((b * 2)-(4 * a * c));
    upper1 = (-b + upper);
    out = upper1 / (2 * a);
    return out;
    }
```

The problem with it is that when I try to compile it I get this error:

```
gcc yl3.c -o ruut -lmyl3.c: In function ‘main’:
yl3.c:16:5: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     printf("Ruutvõrrandi lahendid on: ", solution);
```

Now what am I doing wrong here. Am I really giving the function too many params?

Comment: Use
printf("Ruutvõrrandi lahendid on: %f", solution);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot format string in printf:

```
printf("Ruutvõrrandi lahendid on: ", solution);
```

should be:

```
printf("Ruutvõrrandi lahendid on: %f", solution);
 //                                ^ %f because soulution in float
```

Comment: always thought this will cause a *run time* error, and not a *compile time* one. Any idea if it is defined to be so or specific gcc behavior?

Comment: @amit you need to know variable number of argument function.. printf takes variable number of arguments and at runtime  using format string read next input argument

Comment: Yea, but in this case it seems the OP got a *compile time* error, which is not explained by your explanation.

Comment: @amit It can only be checked at compile time. At runtime, the called function doesn't know how many arguments it got or their type.

Comment: @amit  OP's original code is _not_ a run time error.  Although not the functionality OP wanted and it is unusual code, there is no UB.  `printf()` will simply print "Ruutvõrrandi lahendid on: ", thus the compile time warning and not compile time error.

Comment: @amit compiler just checks how many format string and how many arguments, it also do type-checks e.g. if you do `int i = 10; printf("%d", &i);`  compiler says `%d` excepts an `int` but passing `int*`

Answer (score 2):

This is because no specifier for `solution` in statement

```
printf("Ruutvõrrandi lahendid on: ", solution);
```

You need `%f` specifier for `solution` to print it.

```
printf("Ruutvõrrandi lahendid on: %f", solution);
```

Comment: always thought this will cause a *run time* error, and not a *compile time* one. Any idea if it is defined to be so or specific gcc behavior?

Comment: This is gcc specific (though other compilers may support this type of diagnostics too). And you should be glad about it. ;-)

Comment: @amit; [Grijesh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460728/c-program-is-giving-a-too-many-arguments-error/21460757#comment32386296_21460759) answered your query.

Comment: @amit; If you compile it with `Werror` flag then it will treated as compile time error. See it [here](http://ideone.com/p7fi6V).

Answer (score 0):

Your last `printf()` is missing a format for `solution`...

Answer (score 0):

U missed format specifier in a printf statement

this

```
 printf("Ruutvõrrandi lahendid on: ", solution);
```

should be

```
 printf("Ruutvõrrandi lahendid on: %f", solution);
```